# How to create unidirectional ManyToOne relation with cascading remove without specifying collection member in one side?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have read this answer: [JPA: unidirectional many-to-one and cascading delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7200221/10043559), it says:

> Cascading REMOVE operations from the parent to the child will require a relation from the parent to the child (not just the opposite)

I need cascading remove, but I don't want to get parent data along with child data, so I removed the `List` member in parent class.

I tried to add `CascadeType.REMOVE` in child class, but I got error when I delete child entity:

*Cannot delete
or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`form_layout`, CONSTRAINT `FK8sfa9k2w1thsay7wyd37597s4` FOREIGN KEY (`form_id`) REFERENCES `form` (`id`))*

Is it possible to accomplish this with some JPA annotation?

**Many** side:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "form")
public class Form {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "create_time")
  private Timestamp createTime;

  @Column(name = "modify_time")
  private Timestamp modifyTime;

  public Form() {}
}
```

**One** side:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "form_layout")
public class FormLayout {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  @JoinColumn(name = "form_id", nullable = false)
  private Form form;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "column_count")
  private Integer columnCount;

  public FormLayout() {}

  public FormLayout(Form form) {
    this.form = form;
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot perform a cascade from the children to parent, only from parent to childrens. This is not due to java, but to SQL databases. Implement the exclusion logic in your service class.