# How to reorder table columns in a SQLITE Database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I have a table with two columns that I'd like to swap.  I want the column with index 5 to be swapped with the column with index 4. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574113/sqlite3-how-to-reorder-columns-in-a-table) from 2013 suggests this might not be possible. Is there a way to do this now?

I am currently using SQLite Manager plugin for Firefox.

Comment: The order of columns in a table is irrelevant. Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: Because we have a large iOS project where every `SELECT` statement would need updating

Comment: @artumi then change your program. Column index should not be an issue, so if your queries need changing  (because for some reason it is) then I suggest you do that now and treat it as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it but with the using of creating new table from existing table.

step 1
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col5,col4 INTO #tab1 FROM tab

step 2
rename the table tab to tab2

step 3
rename tab1 to tab

this process might help you.

but if you move column in existing table there is possibility to corrupt the data.