# Rails add multiple columns after a specific column using sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, sqlite3-ruby

I've generated Devise for *User* and now I want to add multiple columns after the *email* column:

```
class AddColumnsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string, after: :email
    add_column :users, :surname, :string, after: :name
    add_column :users, :phone, :integer, after: :surname
    add_column :users, :favourites, :integer, after: :favourites
  end
end
```

but this code adding these columns at the end of table. I use sqlite3 as database in my app. Is it possible to do it in this configuration (rails 7 + sqlite3)?

Comment: Most RDBMS wont actually let you reorder the columns without recreating the entire table. If the column order actually matters you're almost certainly doing something very wrong. I also don't understand where  you got `after: :email` when no such option exists. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column

Comment: Email column is generated by Devise in this case. I was based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481733/ruby-on-rails-add-a-column-after-a-specific-column-name
It works well with rails 4.

Comment: I doubt it worked in Rails 4 either since SQLite doesn't actually let you redefine the column order - altering the table will always add the columns on the end. And doing so would do nother except satisfy your OCD when viewing the table in admin tools. Column order does not matter.

Comment: If you really want to do this you would have to rename the table. Create a new table with all the columns in the order you want and then move all the data from the old table to the new table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574113/sqlite3-how-to-reorder-columns-in-a-table

Comment: The `after:` option most likely just worked in MySQL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934312/how-to-rearrange-mysql-columns

Comment: Thank you for answer. This rails 4 app use MySQL, so it depends on type of database, not rails version.