# Cannot Update cart in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, cart

I am facing a big problem in magento.

i am able to update the cart items when i am not login with the customer. but when i login with the customer then it says **Cannot update the cart**.

I enabled logs it says:-

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint 
fails
(`databasename`.`wishlist`, CONSTRAINT
 `FK_WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID`
  FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
 REFERENCES `customer_entity_old` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CA)
```

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

I solved that problem hope its help. Please see this link ["How to change the foreign key referential action?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359329/how-to-change-the-foreign-key-referential-action-behavior)

I run two queries into my Database as below:

I simply drop CONSTRAINT from the table, and then add the new CONSTRAINT in the table:

1. Drop old:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `wishlist`
   DROP FOREIGN KEY 
   `FK_WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID`;
   ```
2. Add new:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `wishlist`
   ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` 
   FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) 
   REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) 
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
   ```