# How can I change the assignment of a foreign key in SQL to point to a different table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

I know the impact of my question, but my case may be unique.

I am trying to create a delta script to apply to other test databases that change a foreign key's child table. For instance:

Table **A** has **some_id** with a foreign key pointing to a column in table **B**

I want to change **some_id** to point to a column in table **C**

I know this could harm and potentially ruin a system if there was already data there, but in my case there is no data in the parent table. I will simply be switching the foreign key to point to a different column of a different table.

Preferably, I would like a script to do this.

Comment: Checkout this [Change the foreign key referential action][1] may be this will help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359329/how-to-change-the-foreign-key-referential-action-behavior?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said, you already know the implications of doing this...

You just need to drop the Foreign Key constraint on your old table.
Then create a new Foreign Key Constraint joining with your new table

Here is an example:

```
-- create test tables
create table A (column1 bigint primary key, column2 varchar(255))
create table B (column1 bigint primary key, column2 varchar(255), column3 bigint)
create table C (column1 bigint primary key, column2 varchar(255), column3 bigint)
alter table B add constraint fk_B_A foreign key (column3) references table1(column1)

-- change the constraints like this
alter table B drop constraint fk_B_A
alter table C add constraint fk_C_A foreign key (column3) references table1(column1)

-- drop test table
drop table A
drop table B
drop table C
```