# How to delete foreign keys fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm doing a school project, and i have the table items, and ticketItems. TicketItems contains a foreign key from the table items (Item_ID). So what if i want to delete one ítem and its ID is also on the another table ?? it'll throw me an error.

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14381227/1080354

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the foreign key referential action? (behavior)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359329/how-to-change-the-foreign-key-referential-action-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when you've got a parent table (`items`) referenced by a child table (`ticketitems`), if you would like to delete an item, you also would like to take an action on the `ticketitems` table.

If you don't and you have no constraint on `ticketitems`, you will leave an orphan row on that table, because the `item_ID` will no more be available.

Probably all you need is to:

`delete from ticketitems where item_ID = ItemIdYouWantToDelete`

Now that you have deleted from `ticketitems` you will be able to delete from `items` too.

When you define a constraint for a foreign key, you can specify how your DBMS will manage that. That is explained in the links in the comments below your question.