# How to delete a row having a foreign key in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have two tables called `users` and `roles`. User can have only one role. 
What I want to do is to delete user by id. But I get following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`supermarket`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `FKcogjq1smjy03v5s2wfegritx6` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `Roles` (`role_id`))
```

As I have understood, I delete row in user which has foreign key. But I couldn't figure out, how to delete row in `roles` table and only after that to delete record in `users` table. How to achieve this doing only one query?

Below is my classes:

```
@Entity
public class Users {
private int userId;
private String login;
private String password;
private Roles roles;

public Users(String login, String password, Roles roles) {
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
    this.roles = roles;
}

public Users() {
}


@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
public Roles getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Roles roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

 //getters and setters
```

Roles:

```
@Entity
public class Roles {
private int roleId;
private String roleName;

@Id
@Column(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
public int getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
}

public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "role_name", nullable = true, length = 14)
public String getRoleName() {
    return roleName;
}

public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
    this.roleName = roleName;
}

}
```

Here is how I delete:

```
 public void deleteCasher(int id) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Users where userId=:id")
            .setParameter("id", id);

    Users user = (Users) query.uniqueResult();

    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();


}
```

So, what I am doing wrong? How to delete a user, also deleting `role`, making one query?

Comment: i think your sample code is wrong .this code will delete user correctly .

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my users table has foreign key. That's why I get exception.

Comment: Delete from users u where u.userid=1 , this query delete use rand execute correctly   ,i dont know why you say get this exception ? I think when delete roles you will get this exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that behavior to be *permanent*, meaning every time a User is deleted, you could change the *foreign key* action now that the table has been created. This directly into MySQL, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359329/how-to-change-the-foreign-key-referential-action-behavior).

Change the constraint from `ON DELETE RESTRICT` to `ON DELETE CASCADE`

```
ALTER TABLE `users` DROP FOREIGN KEY `FKcogjq1smjy03v5s2wfegritx6`; 

ALTER TABLE `users` ADD CONSTRAINT `FKcogjq1smjy03v5s2wfegritx6`
  FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `Roles` (`role_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible Reasons--

1-- while creating user if you are creating roles in role table with respective userid

2-- if you are using userid in other table as FOREIGN KEY....