# How can I Remove A Duplicate Foreign Key from Multiple Tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a query which finds duplicate results in one table **Table A** based on a foreign key from **Table X**. **Table A**'s Primary key is then a foreign key to 3 other tables, **Table B + Table C + Table D**

Is there a way I can write a *single* script to remove the first *(top)* row of 3 tables  (**Tables B C D**)which use the FK and then **Table A** (via the FK of **Table X**).

Hope this makes sense, it's very hard to explain!!

Table A

---

```
Primary Key                                   Foreign Key                   IsActive

a64c3cae-8474-4c4e-8108-14898b8b5319    3b7c82d9-bbbe-4504-9dfd-e01614d12ff6    1
```

Table B

---

```
Primary Key                                       Foreign Key               IsActive
998852b4-6d2a-47e0-b9c3-497548b8b5c6    a64c3cae-8474-4c4e-8108-14898b8b5319    1
```

Table C

---

```
Primary Key                                 Foreign Key                     IsActive
0966f8e6-4c29-4e5a-8b59-5ac413557392    a64c3cae-8474-4c4e-8108-14898b8b5319    1
```

Table D

---

```
Primary Key                                     Foreign Key                 IsActive
f8c30ff5-498f-4e34-90c5-814bc5cf46ef    a64c3cae-8474-4c4e-8108-14898b8b5319    1
```

Table X

---

```
Primary Key                             Name    InTables
3b7c82d9-bbbe-4504-9dfd-e01614d12ff6    Bob         4
```

---

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Sample data such as 'abc' is much easier than '3b7c82d9-bbbe-4504-9dfd-e01614d12ff6'.

Comment: Noted, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute it in one query like this :

```
DELETE A, B, C, D
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableX X ON X.PK = A.FK
INNER JOIN TableB B ON B.FK = A.PK 
INNER JOIN TableC C ON C.FK = A.PK
INNER JOIN TableD D ON D.FK = A.PK;
```

However, this is not a good practice, as you can use foreign key CONSTRAINT `ON DELETE CASCADE` to be more efficient. What it does it's just link the foreign key to the linked primary key, if you delete that a linked primary key, any linked foreign key will be deleted as well.

[Review this post to know more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359329/how-to-change-the-foreign-key-referential-action-behavior)

Comment: thanks but getting `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','`.

Comment: @SCramphorn is your table name like this `Table A` ? if yes, then enclose your tables name with  ` symbol.