# Generating a select query from a generalized and specialized tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

So I have a generalised table called beneficiaries which gives the specialised table parent and child. So parent and child table reference a beneficiary id. However, child table references a parent beneficiary id. Now my struggle is I want to write a query which returns the name of the child from the beneficiary and the name of the parent from the beneficiary while showing which parent a child belongs to. I wrote this query:

```
select * from beneficiaries
inner join child on beneficiaries.bene_id = child.ParentBene_id
inner join parent on beneficiaries.bene_id = parent.parentBene_id;
```

But the results I get is just the parent name and the id for the child.
Structure of Tables

[Beneficiaries table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjk3h.png)

[Child Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2VvB.png)

[Parent Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRTDL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks great. I created some tables with sample data and this is my result.

[image]

Maybe you forgot to declare the foreigns keys when creating the tables?
Here is the commands I used to create your tables in MySQL:

- Beneficiaries table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `beneficiaries` (
  `bene_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kayacare_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` tinytext,
  `mname` tinytext,
  `lname` tinytext,
  `location` tinytext,
  `dob` tinytext,
  `sex` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bene_id`)
)
```

- Child table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `bene_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentBene_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `healthWorker_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `careGiver_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `parentBene_id` (`parentBene_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (parentBene_id) REFERENCES beneficiaries(bene_id)
  )
```

- Parents table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `parentBene_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `parentBene_id` (`parentBene_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (parentBene_id) REFERENCES beneficiaries(bene_id)
)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359329/how-to-change-the-foreign-key-referential-action-behavior) you can see how to edit a foreign key in MySQL.

Comment: Yes, so the thing is I want the parent name, to show in the query results as well so that we can identify a child and a parent together

Comment: If you only want the names or to have it as your first values in the result, you can ask then like this: `select fname, lname, mname from beneficiaries inner join child on beneficiaries.bene_id = child.ParentBene_id inner join parent on beneficiaries.bene_id = parent.parentBene_id;` I assume that is the parent name, if you are looking for child names, you don't have any field like that in your table.

Answer (score 0):

To get the results I wanted I used this query:

```
select * from child
right join beneficiaries on child.bene_id = beneficiaries.bene_id  
inner join (select parentBene_id,fname as pfname, mname as pmname, lname as plname, phone from 
parent inner join beneficiaries on parent.parentBene_id = beneficiaries.bene_id) 
parent on child.parentBene_id = parent.parentBene_id;
```