# Find all foreign key reference with particular column and change it with new column

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have table `task` which has three fields, `id`, `title` and `user`.

I have added a new field, `taskId`, using `ALTER TABLE task ADD COLUMN taskId INT NOT NULL AFTER id;`

Now column name `id` from `task` table is used as a foreign key reference in many tables.

Second table, `taskMisc`, has two columns, `taskId` and `isStarred`,
and `taskId` is using reference as `id` from `task` table. It's like that for many tables.

How can I change all references at once?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359329/how-to-change-the-foreign-key-referential-action-behavior)

Comment: selectting al tables from information schema and running a loop that changes will take more time than making that manually as you only need to do it once